# neo4j query performance - getting nodes with degree >1

Tags: neo4j, cypher

match (n:A)-[r:Transaction]-(m:B) with n,count(r) num where num>1 return n

[image: explain of query]

There are 100M nodes and 250M relations in the graph. 
The above query is a simple group by in a relational DB and returns in < 5mins. It takes forever in Cypher, any ideas what can make it faster

Comment: It is possible to direct the relation?  (n:A)-[r:Transaction]->(m:B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want nodes of type `A` that have more than one `:Transaction` relationship with one or more nodes of type `B`?

Try

```
MATCH (n:A) WHERE size((n:A)-[:Transaction]-(m:B)) > 1
RETURN n
```

Check out [this blog post](http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-2-2-query-tuning/) for more on efficient relationship counting.